# .htaccess rewrite url - from ~username - osx apache

Tags: macos, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Hi i am using apache on mac, i have enabled php. I am trying to rewrite my url using .htacess.

```
http://localhost/~username/project/test  to http://localhost/~username/project/index.php?url=test
But received 404 error - on retrieving url - http://localhost/~username/project/test .

But - this - http://localhost/~username/project/index.php?url=test - Php is working fine.
```

My .htacess file contains these five lines:

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

I can see mod_rewrite in loaded modules in php info. How I can debug this to find out whether .htaccess is being called or not.

Path of my .htaccess file is - ~username/Sites/project/.htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

From [Troubleshooting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#troubleshoot)

> Make sure that you don't have a AllowOverride None in effect for the file scope in question. A good test for this is to put garbage in your .htaccess file and reload the page. If a server error is not generated, then you almost certainly have AllowOverride None in effect.

Or the other way round, add some garbage to the htaccess, i.e.

```
Foobar
```

and reload the page. If you get some `500` server error message, htaccess (`AllowOveride`) is enabled.